# impossible to install xmonad-contrib using cabal

Tags: debian, gnome, xmonad

I'm trying to recompile my xMonad configuration. I know I have to install the ghc packages xmonad and xmonad-contrib. To do this I installed a lot a debian packages including :

- ghc
- cabal-install
- libghc-xmonad-dev
- libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev

When I do `cabal-install xmonad` everthing works fine. But when doing `cabal install xmonad-contrib` I get the following error

`XMonad/Util/Invisible.hs:31:59:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Applicative’`

I found a discussion about this problem on an archlinux forum but nothing worked for me ([url](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195366))

I'm running debian 8.0. Uname is : `Linux guillaume-X99A 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3 (2015-04-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I'm running Xmonad now (with the default config because I am unable to compile it)

If you have any idea how to make this package compile (or a way to recompile my config without this package) any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: If you installed xmonad and contrib with apt, why do you want to reinstall it with cabal ? You should probably not mix and match packages from different sources, they could have different versions. This is what the thread you linked says.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I ghc packages installed were installed in `/usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d` but not in `/home/guillaume/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d`. I just copied them and everything was working.

Thank you